# Identify duplicate values in specific fields of a multi line file in python

Tags: python, string, list

I am trying to identify duplicate values of the uid field (field 3, delimited by : ) in /etc/passwd

The file looks like this

```
_teamsserver:*:200:94:TeamsServer:/var/teamsserver:/usr/bin/false
_update_sharing:*:95:-2:Update Sharing:/var/empty:/usr/bin/false
_installer:*:96:-2:Installer:/var/empty:/usr/bin/false
_atsserver:*:97:97:ATS Server:/var/empty:/usr/bin/false
_ftp:*:98:-2:FTP Daemon:/var/empty:/usr/bin/false
_unknown:*:99:99:Unknown User:/var/empty:/usr/bin/false
_softwareupdate:*:200:200:Software Update Service:/var/empty:/usr/bin/false
```

I want to return the first and last line since they both have '200' as their uid (field 3)

I tried to use string.split(":") but that puts each field into a list and I only want the thrid field of each line, instead of every field.

I know I can do this in bash with

```
bad=$(awk -F ":" '{print $3}' stupidfile.txt | sort | uniq -d); for i in $bad; do  grep $i stupidfile.txt
```

but I am trying to improve my practical python abilities and know there is probably something simple I'm missing here

Comment: If `l` is a list then `l[2]` returns its third element. So `mystring.split(':')[2]` gives what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the uid's as keys in a dict and a list como to return all values with a `len > 1`:

```
d = {}
with open("in.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        spl = line.split(":")[2]
        d.setdefault(spl,[])
        d[spl].append(line)
repeated  =  [v for v in d.values() if len(v) > 1]
```

Or use a [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) which is faster:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
with open("in.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        spl = line.split(":")[2]
        d[spl].append(line)
repeated  =  [v for v in d.values() if len(v) > 1]
```

Comment: These both successfully execute but return nothing for me using the example in my OP as a txt file...

Comment: did you `print repeated`?

Comment: woops i skimmed too quick, it works with the print statement, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track.

```
l = ['_teamsserver:*:200:94:TeamsServer:/var/teamsserver:/usr/bin/false',
     '_update_sharing:*:95:-2:Update Sharing:/var/empty:/usr/bin/false',
     '_installer:*:96:-2:Installer:/var/empty:/usr/bin/false',
     '_atsserver:*:97:97:ATS Server:/var/empty:/usr/bin/false',
     '_ftp:*:98:-2:FTP Daemon:/var/empty:/usr/bin/false',
     '_unknown:*:99:99:Unknown User:/var/empty:/usr/bin/false',
     '_softwareupdate:*:200:200:Software Update Service:/var/empty:/usr/bin/false']
```

Preprocessing

```
uids = [i.split(':')[2] for i in l]       # strip out a list of the uids
unique = set(uids)                        # make a set of the unique uids
counts = {i : uids.count(i) for i in unique}  # count them in a dictionary
```

Now the actual reporting

```
for line in l:
    uid = line.split(':')[2]
    if counts[uid] > 1:                   # check if its duplicated
        print line


_teamsserver:*:200:94:TeamsServer:/var/teamsserver:/usr/bin/false
_softwareupdate:*:200:200:Software Update Service:/var/empty:/usr/bin/false
```

Comment: If I've read the OP correctly, the output should be `'200'` - so you need a duplicate check here...

Comment: @JonClements You're correct, I didn't finish the rest of their problem, I just took a step towards it, I'll update my post with the rest.

Comment: This returns Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "uidfinder.py", line 15, in <module>
    if counts[uid] > 1:                   # check if its duplicated
TypeError: 'set' object has no attribute '__getitem__'


I even tried copying your code line for line

Comment: you cannot use `set[]`, `counts` is a not a `dict`

Comment: My bad! I edited the dict comp in my code but not the post, see my most recent edit.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach, this time using regex

```
import re
from collections import defaultdict

file = '''_teamsserver:*:200:94:TeamsServer:/var/teamsserver:/usr/bin/false
_update_sharing:*:95:-2:Update Sharing:/var/empty:/usr/bin/false
_installer:*:96:-2:Installer:/var/empty:/usr/bin/false
_atsserver:*:97:97:ATS Server:/var/empty:/usr/bin/false
_ftp:*:98:-2:FTP Daemon:/var/empty:/usr/bin/false
_unknown:*:99:99:Unknown User:/var/empty:/usr/bin/false
_softwareupdate:*:200:200:Software Update Service:/var/empty:/usr/bin/false'''


if __name__ == '__main__':

    search_pattern = re.compile('([\d]+).*', re.MULTILINE)
    uids = [int(uid) for uid in re.findall(search_pattern, file)]
    res = defaultdict(list)

    for uid in uids:
        line_pattern = re.compile('%d.*' % uid, re.MULTILINE)
        lines = re.findall(line_pattern, file)
        if len(lines) > 1:
            res[uid] = lines

    print('res:', res)
```

Output:

```
uids: [200, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 200]
res: {200: ['200:94:TeamsServer:/var/teamsserver:/usr/bin/false', '200:200:Software Update Service:/var/empty:/usr/bin/false']}
```